# Convert dbId to Node

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm  trying to convert a `dbId` to `node` to use the function `setNodeOff()`

In  this [link](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/01/view-and-data-api-tips-conversion-between-dbid-and-node.html), author describe the method `dbIdToNode` but I get an undefined error when I use it : 
(v is my viewer)

[image]

If I check `v.model.getData() .instanceTree`, I get no `undefined` error :

[image]

How I can convert a dbId to a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to convert `dbId` to `node` to use the function `setNodeOff()`

This line will work: `viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(dbId, true);`

Comment: Got another case were I need the node. Same problem as in question. dbIdToNode does not exist?